# Incorrect answer voted to top for city capitalization

Tags: discussion

Could a few of you please upvote the [correct answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/112389/29008) on [this question about capitalizing municipalities](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/112387/29008) and/or downvote the [incorrect one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/144175/29008)? This is an common capitalizing error and we don't need to increase the confusion here.

I'd mistakenly upvoted the incorrect answer before having read the style guides, pushing the incorrect answer to the top, and ran past the time limit of changing your vote.

Comment: I prefer the answer you’ve described as incorrect. Things like capitalization are not set in stone. And the answer you prefer uses Wikipedia as a support,when that source is extremely unreliable.

Answer (score 10):

Just because AP doesn't like the "incorrect" one doesn't actually make it incorrect. It's a style guide, albeit fairly authoritative in American English.

However, the answer mentions the City of London, and **that use is indeed correct.** "The City" means "The City of London" (a semi-autonomous borough, for want of a more understandable explanation), and does not mean "the city of London" (the entire metropolitan area).

Answer (score 9):

The one you identify as "correct" is a decent answer, and I upvoted. The one you identify as "incorrect" is actually not wrong, but it does lack supporting research. I've offered a supporting document in the comment thread.